# Qt regex not matching

Tags: c++, qt, qregexp

Qt's regex (C++) is not working as I expect. For example, in the following line (spaces as full stops)

```
.....mRNA............complement(join(<85666..86403,86539..>86727))
```

"mRNA" is not matched by:

```
QRegExp rxItem("^\\s{5}(\\w+)") ;
```

But is matched by the following:

```
QRegExp rxItem("\\s{4}(\\w+)") ;
```

So it looks as if the start of the line and the first space is not being recognised for some reason. I checked-out the Qt documentation for QRegExp and as far as I can tell "^" signifies the start of a line and \s is space as in Perl.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Does the number of spaces matter to you?  If not then just match zero or more `\s*(\w+)` or one or more `\s+(\w+)`.

Comment: The number of spaces does matter I'm afraid.

Comment: Looks like a bug then as your match string looks good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code:

```
#include <QtCore/QRegExp>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString test = "     mRNA            complement(join(<85666  86403,86539  >86727))";
    QRegExp rxItem( "^\\s{5}(\\w+)" );

    if( rxItem.indexIn( test ) != -1 )
    {
        qDebug() << "Matched" << rxItem.cap( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "No match";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

displays

```
Matched "mRNA"
```

So it seems to be working. Did you maybe treat a result of 0 returned by `indexIn` as error?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I was looking for values > 0 returned by indexIn before printing captured texts. Your way works.